# Not Getting Mobile Handset Correct Screen size using Tera-WURFL

Tags: php, android, web-services, mobile, wurfl

In my PHP Script i have used **Tera-WURFL**  api to get the Screen resolution of mobile Handset
but the result i am getting is not correct... here is a code ...

```
**<?php
require_once('Tera-Wurfl/TeraWurfl.php');

$wurflObj = new TeraWurfl(); 

$wurflObj->getDeviceCapabilitiesFromAgent();

echo "Markup: ".$wurflObj->getDeviceCapability("preferred_markup");

// see the display resolution
$width = $wurflObj->getDeviceCapability("resolution_width");
$height = $wurflObj->getDeviceCapability("resolution_height");
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
echo "<br/>Resolution: $width x $height<br/>";
?>**
```

What i have done wrong here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download and use free 51Degrees.mobi Lite data and documentation from: http://sourceforge.net/projects/fiftyone/?source=directory

You can use 51Degrees.mobi properties using the following code:

```
 <?php
require_once('51Degrees.mobi.php');

$ScreenPixelsHeight = $_51d["ScreenPixelsHeight"];
$ScreenPixelsWidth = $_51d["ScreenPixelsWidth"];

?>
```

Note: All the data stored in the $_51d array is stored as strings, you may have to convert $ScreenPixelsHeight and $ScreenPixelsWidth into a number.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's quite ok to do self-promotion here. HOwever, if you are affiliated with this product, please make that clear in your answer, otherwise your post might end up being flagged as spam.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the library correctly.  The problem is probably related to the user agent of the device that your're testing with.  If, for example, you are testing with a desktop web browser, it is impossible to tell what the resolution is, since this information is not conveyed in the user agent, and cannot be inferred.

Please note that I am the author of Tera-WURFL.